# io error on no-match glob within cifs OSX -> debian jessie mount

Tags: bash, mount, cifs, wildcard, debian-jessie

Using a wildcard/glob (at least `*` and `?`) in `bash` causes an `input/output error` when there are no matches on a samaba `cifs` mount in Debain Jessie 8.2. On other filesystems, the expected `No such file` error is given.

The same samaba mount point on an archlinux box and has no io error. The Archlinux machine's `mount.cifs` understands `mapposix`. I suspect that `mount.cifs` on jessie does not allow/understand `mapposix` has something to do with this.

Is there away around io errors for `*`?

---

```
 ## works as expected on cifs mount from centos server
 ls /data/Luna1/*adfadf*
 # ls: cannot access /data/Luna1/*adfadf*: No such file or director


 ### unexpected io failure on osx mounted on debian
 mkdir /Volumes/Phillips/testdir

 ## no files match in empty directory: io error
 ls /Volumes/Phillips/testdir/*
 #  ls: reading directory /Volumes/Phillips/testdir/*: Input/output error

 ## glob matches, ls results
 touch /Volumes/Phillips/testdir/file
 ls /Volumes/Phillips/testdir/*
 #  /Volumes/Phillips/testdir/file

 ## glob matches, ls results
 ls /Volumes/Phillips/testdir/*il*
 # /Volumes/Phillips/testdir/file

 ## no files match: io error
 ls /Volumes/Phillips/testdir/*foobar*
 #  ls: reading directory /Volumes/Phillips/testdir/*foobar*: Input/output error

 # fails as expected
 ls /*filedoesnotexist*
 #  ls: cannot access /*filedoesnotexist*: No such file or directory

 ## zsh handles this correctly
 zsh -c "ls /Volumes/Phillips/*dne*"
 #  zsh:1: no matches found: /Volumes/Phillips/*dne*
```

System info:

```
cat /etc/debian_version 
   8.2  
dpkg -l cifs-utils 
   ii  cifs-utils     2:6.4-1      amd64        Common Internet File 


mount |grep cifs
//gromit/Luna1/ on /data/Luna1 type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=foranw,domain=GROMIT,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=10.145.64.52,unix,posixpaths,serverino,nobrl,acl,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,actimeo=1)

//skynet/Phillips/ on /Volumes/Phillips type cifs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=lncd,domain=SKYNET,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=10.145.64.109,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,nobrl,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,actimeo=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to touch a file that matches the glob to avoid an error

This works particularly well for FSL's `bet` where `rm` is called with a glob that matches nothing. Interestingly, it throws "directory exists" (when it does not) instead of IO error.

```
bet 002_mprage_hpf 002_mprage_hpf_brain -m -f 0.1
# /bin/rm: cannot remove '002_mprage_hpf_brain_tmp*': Is a directory.
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo failed
# failed
```

vs

```
touch 002_mprage_hpf_brain_tmp_hackyhackhack
bet 002_mprage_hpf 002_mprage_hpf_brain -m -f 0.1
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo failed
# $? == 0
```